Parsing subnets with CIDR notation
Having problem with my ARP scanner.
I have functions to parse inputed subnets to IP Range which i can iterate through so i can send ARP requests to network and return alive hosts on network.
I can see via Wireshark app is generating ARP packets but with wrong subnets.
For example when i input subnet 192.168.1.1/24 in wireshark i see 1.1.168.X instead of 192.168.1.X

Also for some reason it doesnt work with 192.168.1.0/24 only with 192.168.1.1/24 with zero on the end it doesnt do nothing.
This is the code for the scanner:
[DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern int SendARP(int DestIP, int SrcIP, byte[] pMacAddr, ref uint PhyAddrLen);

private static uint macAddrLen = (uint)new byte[6].Length;

private async Task PerformArpScan()
{
    ScanResults.Clear();
    foreach (var subnet in Subnets)
    {
        var (networkAddress, cidr) = ParseSubnet(subnet);
        var hosts = GenerateIPRange(networkAddress, cidr).ToList();

        var results = new ConcurrentBag<ScanResult>();

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(hosts, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20 }, ip =>
            {
                var result = SendArpRequest(ip);
                if (result != null)
                {
                    results.Add(result);
                }
            });
        });

        await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                ScanResults.Add(result);
            }
        });
    }
}

private ScanResult SendArpRequest(IPAddress ipAddress)
{
    byte[] macAddr = new byte[6];
    uint macAddrLen = (uint)macAddr.Length;

    try
    {
        int result = SendARP(BitConverter.ToInt32(ipAddress.GetAddressBytes().Reverse().ToArray(), 0), 0, macAddr, ref macAddrLen);

        if (result == 0)
        {
            string macAddressString = string.Join(":", macAddr.Take((int)macAddrLen).Select(b => b.ToString("X2")));
            return new ScanResult
            {
                IpAddress = ipAddress.ToString(),
                MacAddress = macAddressString,
                Status = "Online",
                OpenPorts = "N/A"
            };
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error sending ARP request to {ipAddress}: {ex.Message}");
    }

    return null;
}

private (IPAddress, int) ParseSubnet(string subnet)
{
    var parts = subnet.Split('/');
    var ip = IPAddress.Parse(parts[0]);
    var cidr = int.Parse(parts[1]);

    // Ensure we're using the network address
    var ipBytes = ip.GetAddressBytes();
    var mask = uint.MaxValue << (32 - cidr);
    var networkBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(BitConverter.ToUInt32(ipBytes, 0) & mask);

    return (new IPAddress(networkBytes), cidr);
}

private IEnumerable<IPAddress> GenerateIPRange(IPAddress networkAddress, int cidr)
{
    byte[] ipBytes = networkAddress.GetAddressBytes();
    uint startIP = BitConverter.ToUInt32(ipBytes, 0) & (uint.MaxValue << (32 - cidr));
    uint endIP = startIP | (uint.MaxValue >> cidr);

    for (uint i = startIP + 1; i < endIP; i++)
    {
        yield return new IPAddress(BitConverter.GetBytes(i));
    }
}


Trying to ARP for the network address (host all zeroes) or the broadcast address (host all ones) is pointless because they are not able to be assigned to network interfaces (except in the case of /31 point-to-point networks that Microsoft does not support). You should only try to ARP with usable host addresses.

@RonMaupin not sure what you mean. In code above im iterating through each ip address in given ip range and send ARP requests for each ip and when i get an answer i know the ip is alive on the network.

What I mean is the first and last addresses in the network are the network address, e.g. 192.168.1.0/24, and the broadcast address, e.g. 192.168.1.255/24, and they are not valid host addresses. You should iterate only through the valid host addresses: network + 1 through broadcast - 1.

Kind of recreated whole function to generate ip range and it works now.
public static IEnumerable<IPAddress> GenerateIPRange(string cidrNotation)
{
    string[] parts = cidrNotation.Split('/');
    if (parts.Length != 2)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid CIDR notation");
    }

    if (!IPAddress.TryParse(parts[0], out IPAddress ipAddress))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid IP address");
    }

    if (!int.TryParse(parts[1], out int subnetBits) || subnetBits < 0 || subnetBits > 32)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid subnet mask");
    }

    uint ipCount = (uint)(1 << (32 - subnetBits));
    byte[] ipBytes = ipAddress.GetAddressBytes();
    uint startIP = (uint)((ipBytes[0] << 24) | (ipBytes[1] << 16) | (ipBytes[2] << 8) | ipBytes[3]);

    for (uint i = 0; i < ipCount; i++)
    {
        uint currentIP = startIP + i;
        byte[] currentIPBytes = new byte[4]
        {
            (byte)(currentIP >> 24),
            (byte)(currentIP >> 16),
            (byte)(currentIP >> 8),
            (byte)currentIP
        };

        yield return new IPAddress(currentIPBytes);
    }
}



There is a likely issue in your GenerateIPRange implementation.  The IPAddress.GetAddressBytes() method will return the bytes in network order (big endian/most significant byte first), whereas BitConverter methods will read in host order (little endian/least significant byte first on x86/64 architectures).  You will need to reverse the byte order, e.g.:
private IEnumerable<IPAddress> GenerateIPRange(IPAddress networkAddress, int cidr)
{
    Action<byte[]> ReverseIfLittleEndian = b => {
           if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) 
                Array.Reverse(b);
           };
    byte[] ipBytes = networkAddress.GetAddressBytes();
    ReverseIfLittleEndian(ipBytes);
    uint startIP = BitConverter.ToUInt32(ipBytes, 0) & (uint.MaxValue << (32 - cidr));

    uint endIP = startIP | (uint.MaxValue >> cidr);

    for (uint i = startIP + 1; i < endIP; i++)
    {
        byte[] ipa = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
        ReverseIfLittleEndian(ipa);
        yield return new IPAddress(ipa);
    }
}

In .NET Core, the BinaryPrimitives class provides methods that incorporate endianness:
using System.Buffers.Binary;
                
private IEnumerable<IPAddress> GenerateIPRange(IPAddress networkAddress, int cidr)
{
    byte[] ipBytes = networkAddress.GetAddressBytes();
    
    uint startIP = BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt32BigEndian(ipBytes) & (uint.MaxValue << (32 - cidr));

    uint endIP = startIP | (uint.MaxValue >> cidr);

    for (uint i = startIP + 1; i < endIP; i++)
    {
        byte[] addr = new byte[sizeof(uint)];
        BinaryPrimitives.WriteUInt32BigEndian(addr, i);
        yield return new IPAddress(addr);
    }
}


Didnt help still the same problem. But recreated whole function and it works now. Im posting it as answer.
